# Is it OK to create and send zero length buffer

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I need to send a large number of small buffers over socket. For that purpose I am thinking to use scatter-gather capability of ASIO library. I presume that scatter-gather is more efficient than sending each buffer separately and in my case it simplifies the logic of completion handler.

Some of buffers can be empty. If a buffer is empty is it OK to add it tobuffer sequence or should it be skipped?

There is `const_buffer` class. It has default constructor that creates empty buffer and 2 argument constructor that created a buffer from a memory range. Is it OK to use the second constructor to create an empty buffer?

Comment: What difference does sending nothing have vs. doing nothing?

Comment: @ta.speot.is usually, sending a zero. as in sort of a "I'm about to send you... nothing." announcement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, sure! as I understand your question, sometimes you may send an empty buffer, which would be equivalent of sending just TCP header (which would be considered as sending *keep-alive*) -- that is quite Ok for TCP/UDP...

if you already have smth to send, you may just skip an empty buffer... or not... is doesn't matter -- final packet will not have any gap between two buffers.